# How is inter module dependencies achieved in wildfly swarm

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-swarm

How is inter module dependencies achieved in wildfly swarm?

For example, I have a module with these contents:

```
    <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.obbi.domain.security">
      <resources>
       <artifact name="com.obbi.domain.platform:domain-service-security-jboss:2.0.86"/>
       <artifact name="com.obbi.domain.platform:domain-service-security-client:2.0.86"/>
      </resources>
      <dependencies>
       <module name="org.jboss.as.web"/>
       <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
       <module name="org.picketbox"/>
       <module name="javax.api"/>
       <module name="javax.security.auth.message.api"/>
       <module name="javax.servlet.api"/>
      </dependencies>
    </module>

At runtime, when I try to access my application, it fails because it can't find the dependencies specified in the module.

2017-07-05 16:58:50,312 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /Test/rest/Ping: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jose4j/json/internal/json_simple/parser/ParseException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
at org.jboss.security.auth.message.config.JBossServerAuthConfig.createSAM(JBossServerAuthConfig.java:244)
at org.jboss.security.auth.message.config.JBossServerAuthConfig.getAuthContext(JBossServerAuthConfig.java:178)
at org.jboss.security.plugins.auth.JASPIServerAuthenticationManager.secureResponse(JASPIServerAuthenticationManager.java:158)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jaspi.JASPICSecureResponseHandler.handleRequest(JASPICSecureResponseHandler.java:35)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:211)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:809)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jose4j.json.internal.json_simple.parser.ParseException from [Module "com.obbi.domain.security:main" from BootModuleLoader@752325ad for finders [BootstrapClasspathModuleFinder, BootstrapModuleFinder(org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap:main), ClasspathModuleFinder, ContainerModuleFinder(swarm.container:main), ApplicationModuleFinder(swarm.application:main), org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.modules.DynamicModuleFinder@279fedbd]]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
... 28 more
```

I have tried copying the dependencies modules from the normal wildfly modules directory into the wildfly swarm resources, but the issue persists.

So how are these dependencies within the module configured?

Regards

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're adding the two artifacts into a module.xml instead of just as dependencies in a WAR?

Maybe some more context around how the module is expected to be used would help

Answer (score 0):

I had to include

```
<artifact name="org.bitbucket.b_c:jose4j:0.5.0"/>
```

in my module.xml, as well as

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bitbucket.b_c</groupId>
    <artifactId>jose4j</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

in my POM.

The issue had nothing to do with inter module dependencies